# Starting Electron with JS file as argument

Tags: electron

When I install the [electron quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/) and run

```
node_modules/.bin/electron --help
```

it tells me:

```
A path to an Electron app may be specified. It must be one of the following:
  - index.js file.
  - Folder containing a package.json file.
  - Folder containing an index.js file.
  - .html/.htm file.
  - http://, https://, or file:// URL.
```

Running

```
node_modules/.bin/electron .
```

(i.e. the option "Folder containing a package.json file") works alright. `package.json` points to `main.js` and looks as follows:

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.1.4"
  }
}
```

I'd assume that running this:

```
node_modules/.bin/electron main.js
```

should work as well, but it does not – it just shows the Electron "dummy" screen.

[image: dummy screen]

How can I specify on the command line which JavaScript to run?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the JavaScript is executed alright – the problem is how the path to the main HTML file is resolved.  Solution: Replace:

```js
mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
```

with:

```js
const arg = process.argv[1]  // better command line parsing might be needed
const dir = fs.lstatSync(arg).isDirectory() ? arg : path.resolve(arg, '..')
mainWindow.loadFile(path.resolve(dir, 'index.html'))
```